# get data from 2 dropdownlist after submitting the form in php

Tags: php

Ive been searching around here to find an answer but I cannot find one :).
My issue I have 2 dropdownlist "manufacturers" and "models". This is for an aircraft directory. What I want is after the user select a manufacturer and model and click "submit", they will be redirected to a page and show the information about a certain aircraft that belongs to that certain manufacturer and model. Just for clarification, I want to show that data after the user click the submit button. I saw a lot of tutorials about getting data from the dropdownlist but all of them used "onchange" for getting and displaying the value from the dropdownlist.

here is the code:

```
<form name="psform" action="pistonsingle.php" method="post">
         <?php 
            $display = displaymaincat(1);
            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
                echo $result['maincategory'];  
            }
          ?>
         <?php 
           $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM manufacturers");
            confirm_query($display);
            echo "<select name=\"manu\">";
            echo "<option> --Select Manufacturer--</option>";
            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
             echo "<option value=$result[id]>$result[manufacturer] </option>";};
             echo "</select>";
         ?>
         <?php 
             $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM models");
            confirm_query($display);
            echo "<select name=\"models\">";
             echo "<option name=\"nullsel\"> --Select Model--</option>";
            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
             echo "<option value=$result[id]>$result[model] </option>";};
             echo "</select>";
         ?>
         <input type="submit" name="psbutton" id="button" value="Show Listing"  />
         </form>
```

Then I try to use this function that i make on the action page
function psdisplay(){

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM individualaircraft 
        INNER JOIN aircraftmaincat on individualaircraft.maincategory_id = aircraftmaincat.id
        INNER JOIN manufacturers on individualaircraft.manufacturer_id = manufacturers.id
        INNER JOIN models on individualaircraft.model_id = models.id
        WHERE maincategory_id = 1");
        confirm_query($display);
        return $display;
    }
        }
```

```
?></td>
<td><?php 
        $display = psdisplay();
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
            echo $result['generalinformation'];
        }
?></td>
<td><?php 
    $display = psdisplay();
        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
            echo $result['website'];
        }

?></td>
```

its working. it displays the data but the problem is when the user click the submit button even he/she select a certain manufacturer or model, what my code do is just display all the aircrafts and not a certain aircraft that belong to a certain manufacturer and model.

I hope somebody can help me :). Thanks in advance.

Keyframer

Answer (score 1):

Hey I don't see anywhere that you actually use the models and manufacturers values. You don't use them in your sql query in the psdisplay() function thats for sure. This might be more what you need.

```
function psdisplay($manufacturer, $model)
        $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM individualaircraft 
        INNER JOIN aircraftmaincat on individualaircraft.maincategory_id = aircraftmaincat.id
        INNER JOIN manufacturers on individualaircraft.manufacturer_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($manufacturer) . "
        INNER JOIN models on individualaircraft.model_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($model) . "
        WHERE maincategory_id = 1") or die(mysql_error());
        confirm_query($display);
        return $display;
}
```

Then change this code to this:

```
<td><?php 
$display = psdisplay($_POST['manu'], $_POST['model']);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
    echo $result['generalinformation'];
}
?></td>
```

Oh and if this does work for you, don't forget to add some validation and also escape the variables in the sql query :)

Comment: I try this one:
function psdisplay($manufacturer){
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM individualaircraft 
   INNER JOIN aircraftmaincat on individualaircraft.maincategory_id = aircraftmaincat.id
   INNER JOIN manufacturers on individualaircraft.manufacturer_id = $manufacturer
   INNER JOIN models on individualaircraft.model_id = models.id
   WHERE maincategory_id = 1");
   confirm_query($display);
            return $display;
        }
            }

Comment: Ill just try first showing the manufacturer but then this error occur.
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejphp\pistonsingle.php on line 31

code at the action page
<?php 
            $display = psdisplay($_POST['manu']);
            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
                echo $result['generalinformation'];
            }
    ?>

Comment: @keyframer Is your form and the above code on the same page? If so then add the form submit check around it. Also if you are allowing the user to omit an option then you'll need to modify the psdisplay function again.

Comment: no. im not allowing the user to omit an option. then the form has a different action page. let say, the dropdownlist is on aircraft.php and the action page is on singleaircraft.php. im sure your code should work out but ill just get this error on singleaircraft.php
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejphp\pistonsingle.php on line 31
it seems like mysql_fetch_array dont like the parameter that was passed on. :)

Comment: @keyframer see the changes I made to my answer. Try that out and see what error you get bacl. Also check to make sure that the values are being posted from the form by dumping them out in singleaircraft.php

Comment: @martswite: about the first error i posted. i do apologize. i changed the name my submit button. lol. but yeah. your code should work but i remember last few days i try to add also a variable for the manufacturers id and models id to get it from the dropdownlist but this error occurs. note: this error occurs with your edited answer too.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE maincategory_id = 1' at line 5..........
It seems like SQL dont like the parameters passed.

Comment: @keyframer is maincategory_id definitely the name of the column in your database?

Comment: maincategory table name is: aircraftmaincat then maincategory is the name of field.
then for individual aircraft i have maincategory_id field innerjoin to maincategory field. the maincategory is i think working fine. it is the manufacturer_id and the model_id that cause the problem.

Comment: you can check the testing website here: http://www.ejaircraft.com/ejphp/aircrafts.php
Click the first manufacturer and the first model.
The codes that you gave was already in the server.
I hope you can help me with this :) thx again.

Comment: @keyframer could you echo the sql query out in pistonsingle.php?

Comment: yeah. i can echo with while statement. when we pass a parameter to get the id from manufacturer and model $manufacturer - $model this error occur. without this parameter i can echo the query. the problem is it is displaying all the list from manufacturers and models even you select one on the dropdownlist.

Comment: i try this.but stil sql error...
if(isset($_POST['psbutton'])){
            $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM individualaircraft 
   INNER JOIN aircraftmaincat on individualaircraft.maincategory_id = aircraftmaincat.id
   INNER JOIN manufacturers on individualaircraft.manufacturer_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['manu']) . "
   INNER JOIN models on individualaircraft.model_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['model']) . "
   WHERE maincategory_id = 1");
   confirm_query($display);
   while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
    echo $result['aircraftname'];
   }
        }

Comment: I Add this line of code:

function psdisplay(){
            if(isset($_POST['psbutton'])){
            $manufacturer = $_POST['manu'];
      $model = $_POST['models'];

Comment: $display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM individualaircraft 
   INNER JOIN aircraftmaincat on individualaircraft.maincategory_id = aircraftmaincat.id
   INNER JOIN manufacturers on individualaircraft.manufacturer_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($manufacturer) . "
   INNER JOIN models on individualaircraft.model_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($model) . "
   WHERE maincategory_id = 1");
   confirm_query($display);
            return $display;
        }
            }

Comment: then on pistongsingle.php this is the code:
<?php 
         $display = psdisplay();
            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($display)){
                echo $result['aircraftname'];
    } 
    ?>

it returns the data but its displays 10x!